# Docker compose-build with rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im trying to set up my app to run in production mode and Ive hit a problem with building the assets folder specifically this line in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname SECRET_TOKEN=dummytoken assets:precompile
```

The database is just a dummy line.  The problem is when it runs the rake it seems to not see the env variables and I get the following errors when it goes to initialize carrierwave.rb

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
/usr/local/bundle/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:27:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
/mnt/hgfs/Projects/livingrecipe/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
/mnt/hgfs/Projects/livingrecipe/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Theres a few more lines to the error but the first line says it all and the ENV variables for the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key dont seem to load up.  If I run this without trying to precompile the assets everything works but I need to precompile the assets to make them visible to nginx

I did find that for a fix I could replace the ENV variables with what they are, this is the code that is having the trouble:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:               'AWS',                             # required
    aws_access_key_id:      ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],            # required
    aws_secret_access_key:  ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],     # required
    region:                 'us-west-2'                        # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']               # required
  #config.fog_host       = 'https://assets.example.com'           # optional, defaults to nil
  #config.fog_public     = false                                  # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

So I got it to work with just typing in the keys...but obviously that isnt a good solution long term to have the keys programmed in.

Comment: Where/how are aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key being set?

Comment: Figured out the specific part of code that is causing it.  It is in a initializer for carrierwave with fog.  I update question with the code

Answer (score 1):

Your question has shifted a bit, so I'm going to address your last sentence:

> So I got it to work with just typing in the keys...but obviously that isn't a good solution long term to have the keys programmed in.

If you're sure you want to handle this during your *build*, as opposed to adding your rake task to your `command` entry, you can set [build args](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/args) in your docker-compose.yml config file.

```
# compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    # ...
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        # This will make your variables available during the
        # "build" phase.
        # You can hardcode these values here, or better, 
        # add them to a .env file, whose contents  
        # Docker/Compose will make available during the build.
        - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        - DATABASE_URL
        - SECRET_TOKEN
    environment:
      # You should also add these values to your application's 
      # environment.
      # You can hardcode these values here, or better, 
      # add them to a .env file, whose contents  
      # Docker/Compose will make available to your running container.
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - DATABASE_URL
      - SECRET_TOKEN
```

You can then declare and use the build args in your Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
# ...
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG DATABASE_URL
ARG SECRET_TOKEN
# these values will now be available to your rake task 
# in ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], etc.
RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production assets:precompile
```